# AngularJs How to filter $cacheFactory

Tags: angularjs, caching

**I have a $cacheFactory in place**

> ```
>  /* @ngInject */
> MenuSvcCache.$inject = ['$cacheFactory'];
>
> app.factory('MenuSvcCache', MenuSvcCache);
> function MenuSvcCache($cacheFactory){
>     return $cacheFactory('MenuSvc')
> };
> ```

**It is used in my LayoutCtrl:**

> ```
>     function Init(router) {
>     if (MenuSvcCache) {
>         layout.menuItems = MenuSvcCache.get('MenuSvc');            
>     } else {
>         MenuSvc.all().success(function (data) {
>             MenuSvcCache.put('MenuSvc', data)
>             layout.menuItems = MenuSvcCache.get('MenuSvc');
>         })
>             .error(function (error) {
>                 console.log('Error: ' + error.message)
>             });
>     }
> }
> ```

**Can I filter that cache at will? Something like ...**

> ```
>         if(MenuSvcCache && router){   
>         layout.menuItems = MenuSvcCache.get('MenuSvc').$filter(router);   
>         } else {
>         layout.menuItems = MenuSvcCache.get('MenuSvc'); 
>         }
> ```

**I realize ".$filter(router)" is not correct syntax, but is there any syntax I can use?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually keep track of the keys - see this plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/vQfo0KAHPxs6K9t437i1?p=preview

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('cacheExampleApp', []).
  controller('CacheController', ['$filter', '$scope', '$cacheFactory',
  function($filter, $scope, $cacheFactory) {
    $scope.keys = [];
    $scope.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheId');
    $scope.put = function(key, value) {
      if ($scope.cache.get(key) === undefined) {
        $scope.keys.push(key);
      }
      $scope.cache.put(key, value === undefined ? null : value);
    };

    $scope.put('apples', {data: 1});
    $scope.put('pears', {data: 2});
    $scope.put('oranges', {data: 3});
    $scope.put('pineapples', {data: 1});
    $scope.put('cherries', {data: 1});

  }]);
})(window.angular);

angular.module('cacheExampleApp').filter('onesOnly', function() {
  return function(cacheEntry) {
      return cacheEntry.data === 1;
  }
})
```